# Sed to add each match to own line

Tags: regex, bash, awk, sed

I have this

```
awk -F=":" -v RS="," '$1~/"name"/ {print}' | sed -e 's/^.*"name"[ ]*:[ ]*"//' -e 's/".*//'`

user1 user2 user3 user4 user5
```

I am trying to add a way of creating each match on its own line instead of side by side

```
user1
user2 
user3 
user4 
user5
```

For a bonus, is there a way of telling the awk and sed to skip the first match of "name"?

This is the output from the api

```
{
  "name": "users",
  "self": "http://",
  "users": {
    "size": 5,
    "items": [
      {
        "self": "http://",
        "name": "admin",
        "emailAddress": "admin@example.com",
        "avatarUrls": {

        },
        "displayName": "admin",
        "active": true
      },
      {
        "self": "http://",
        "name": "user1",
        "emailAddress": "user1@example.com",
        "avatarUrls": {

        },
        "displayName": "user1",
        "active": true
      },
      {
        "self": "http://",
        "name": "user2",
        "emailAddress": "user2@example.com",
        "avatarUrls": {

        },
        "displayName": "user2",
        "active": true
      },
      {
        "self": "http://",
        "name": "user3",
        "emailAddress": "user3@example.com",
        "avatarUrls": {

        },
        "displayName": "user3",
        "active": true
      }
    ],
    "max-results": 50,
    "start-index": 0,
    "end-index": 3
  },
  "expand": "users"
}
```

Comment: What is your input? Also `-F=":"` is setting your `FS` to `=:` not `:` like you might be expecting. Either use `-F:` or `-v FS=:`.

Comment: Also in general if you are using `awk | sed` you are doing something wrong. `awk` can almost certainly do what you want itself easily enough.

Comment: The input is a json response from a rest api, It has extra information so I am trying to get just the users name

Comment: I have added the input.

Comment: Missing expected output for json

Comment: about skipping the first name, i think you can use the indent to notify awk about this. i.e., you require the matching of name in a deep enough indent.

Comment: change you sed code into this: `sed -n 's/\s*"name"\s*:\s*"\([^"]*\)".*/\1/p'`. and it's gonna come line by line.

Comment: Did you consider using a more dedicated tool such as https://github.com/micha/jsawk or http://stedolan.github.io/jq ?

Comment: +1 for what @damienfrancois said. Don't use awk/sed/etc. for this use a json tool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using just `awk` to interpret the sample json data:

```
$ awk -F: -v RS="," '$1~/"name"/ && f {gsub("[ \",]", "", $2); print $2} $1~/"name"/{f=1}' json
admin
edwin
niwde
other
```

The first match of `name` is skipped due to the flag `f`.

*Explanation of `awk` code:*

- `$1~/"name"/ && f {gsub("[ \",]", "", $2); print $2}`

  This consists of a condition and a group of statements.  The condition requires that the first field match `"name"` *and* that the flag `f` is nonzero.  If both those conditions are met, then spaces, quotes, and commas are removed from the same second field and the second field is printed.

  In `awk`, the default value for variables is zero (or blank). Consequently, nothing is printed until we assign `f` a non-zero value.
- `$1~/"name"/{f=1}`

  If the first field matches on `"name"`, then the flag `f` is set to `1`.  Thus, `f` is not set to `1` until after the first name field is seen.  Thus, the first name field will not be printed but all after it will be.

Comment: Thank you, this worked great and for your explanation. How would I go as to adding each of the names in a separate line?

Comment: @jquerynoob For me, each name does print on a separate line, just as shown in the sample output in my answer.  Does it not do that for you?  Or, are you asking about something else?

Answer (score 2):

You can try this sed

```
sed -n '/"name": "/{s/ *"name": "\([^"]*\)",/\1/;p}' YourFile
```

Comment: Nicely done.  If you like, You can filter that command through `tail -n+2` to remove the first match as wanted for the OP's "bonus."  Also the sed command can be simplified to `sed -n 's/ *"name": "\([^"]*\)",/\1/p'`